# Example query from my textbook is coming up with an Error message. "Ambiguous column name 'V_CODE'"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ambiguous

For my homework, I have to enter example queries from the book to sql. There are also example database I downloaded for the homework and properly put them into SQL. The following is what I have to put in but an error message comes up.

```
SELECT V_CODE, V_NAME, V_STATE, P_CODE, P_DESCRIPT, P_PRICE * P_QOH AS TOTAL
FROM PRODUCT P JOIN VENDOR V ON P.V_CODE = V.V_CODE
WHERE V_STATE IN ('TN','KY')
ORDER BY V_STATE, TOTAL DESC;

--Total value of products from Tennessee and Kentucky
```

> Ambiguous column name 'V_CODE'

Not sure how to fix.

I had to put in an example query from the homework but an error message comes up.

"Ambiguous column name 'V_CODE'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose which table you are choosing `V_CODE` from. In this example it's taken from the `PRODUCT` table.

```
SELECT P.V_CODE, V_NAME, V_STATE, P_CODE, P_DESCRIPT, P_PRICE * P_QOH AS TOTAL
FROM PRODUCT P JOIN VENDOR V ON P.V_CODE = V.V_CODE
WHERE V_STATE IN ('TN','KY')
ORDER BY V_STATE, TOTAL DESC;
--Total value of products from Tennessee and Kentucky
```

Comment: I thought it was already taking from the product table, is the rest of the "FROM" line an issue here? What would cause this?

Comment: You are joining two tables here, it's always *good practice* to qualify your selected columns with the table alias, that way it's obvious when reading the query from which table each column originates. When a column name is only in a single table, SQL Server doesn't require the alias specifically, internally it expands the column names to include the table name - however clearly `V_CODE` column is in both tables for you to able able to join on it - so which column of the two it can choose from should SQL Server use? It may be obvious to you or I that it doesn't actually matter...

Comment: ... but SQL Server still requires you to be precise.